# degree symbol in Python triple-quoted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, special-characters

It appears that the Python 3.7 interpreter won't accept a module that has triple-quoted strings containing special characters like the degree symbol.  (I don't want to use an encoding for the degree symbol because the comments are the benefit of someone looking at the code, which will then become less intelligible).  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: What do you mean *"won't accept"*? Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: "I don't want to use an encoding..." Then you're out of luck. ASCII is common enough to assume everyone wanting to read your code *can* read plain text, but anything beyond **must** be encoded in some way. Even if it's a lousy Latin-1 encoding. What's wrong with putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file and let a hypothetical text viewer work it out from there? See the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: By *"I don't want to use an encoding"* I assume the OP means not wanting to use an escape sequence like `\u00B0`.

Comment: kaya3's assumption is correct.  Here's my code:

    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   """
    This Python script, when used in conjunction with the Python 3.7 interpreter,
    demonstrates that the interpreter won't accept the degree symbol (°) in a
    triple-quoted string.
    """

    print("Hello!")

Here's the output:

>python special_char.py
  File "special_char.py", line 7
    """
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 145: invalid start byte.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reproduced if the Python file is incorrectly encoded with an 8-bit encoding instead of UTF-8.  The byte `0xb0` maps to the degree symbol in many 8-bit encodings, as can be seen [here](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#b0).

The error is reproduced if the python file is encoded as latin-1

```bash
iconv --from-code=utf-8 --to-code=latin1 special_char.py > latin_1_char.py
python3.7 latin_1_char.py 
  File "latin_1_char.py", line 4
    """
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 145: invalid start byte
```

or as cp1252

```bash
iconv --from-code=utf-8 --to-code=cp1252 char.py > cp1252_char.py
(so38) kdwyer@osiris:~/p/so38  $ python3.7 cp1252_char.py 
  File "cp1252_char.py", line 4
    """
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 145: invalid start byte
```

but not if the file is encoded as utf-8

```bash
iconv --from-code=latin1 --to-code=utf-8 latin_1_char.py > utf8_char.py
python3.7 utf8_char.py 
Hello!
```